# g++ curly quotes displayed incorrectly in console and "Problems" list

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, cygwin, g++, eclipse-cdt

Recently, I switched from Visual Studio to Eclipse CDT. I've set it up beautifully such that the G++ compiler from my Cygwin installation can locate and compile my code without ado.

There is a minor grievance, however. Each time G++ reports a warning or error, the curly single quotes `‘` and `’` appear as `â€˜` respectively `â€™`. It seems like a character encoding problem; G++ or Cygwin is spitting out a character encoding that either CDT or Eclipse doesn't like.

[This is only relevant Google result I could find](http://markmail.org/message/i2633yoxediif4ef#query:+page:1+mid:6nygf2cd6uolxpl4+state:results), but setting the C++ environment variable `LANG` in Eclipse's preferences to `C.UTF-8` or `en_US.UTF-8` has no effect.

Running C++ from Cygwin directly reveals the curly single quotes. Is there any way of disabling these altogether? Is there some environment variable I can set or an argument I can pass?

### In images

Eclipse shows hieroglyphs in various places:

[image: Eclipse's problem screen]
[image: Eclipse's console screen]

Cygwin shows the correct symbols (ignore the fatal error):

[image: Cywgin reveals the symbol]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, you either have to get Eclipse to display UTF-8, or to stop Cygwin gcc from using it. I don't know how to do the former, but you can do the latter by making sure that gcc is run with something like LANG=en_US.ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I added an environment variable `LANG` with value `en_US.ISO-8859-1` in Eclipse preferences, and now the characters display more legibly.

Answer (score 5):

According to gcc 4.0 release notes http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.0/changes.html:

> English-language diagnostic messages will now use Unicode quotation marks in UTF-8 locales. (Non-English messages already used the quotes appropriate for the language in previous releases.) If your terminal does not support UTF-8 but you are using a UTF-8 locale (such locales are the default on many GNU/Linux systems) then you should set `LC_CTYPE=C` in the environment to disable that locale. Programs that parse diagnostics and expect plain ASCII English-language messages should set `LC_ALL=C`. See [Markus Kuhn's explanation of Unicode quotation marks](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me too. The environment variable need to be set in the Eclipse preferences window under C/C++/Build/Environment. You need to add a new variable by clicking on the Add button. The variable name should be set to LANG and the value to en_US.ISO-8859-1. Does anyone know what is the cause of the problem? Cygwin, Eclipse, gcc???

Comment: Please post this as a comment to ak2's answer instead. That way he'll be notified of your response.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 2 worked best for me when using gcc in a cygwin rxvt terminal.

Within my .bash_profile added:

# Disable unicode quotation marks for gcc

export LC_CTYPE=C